# How can I replicate a table in a python dictionary? (or any other data structure)

Tags: python, data-structures, ms-word

I have a table in which a few cells are merged, from the XML I'm able to get the rows -> cells -> data and gridspan(how many cells are merged into this cell in the following row).

Now what I need to do is to get the sum of all the cells in a row and verify it with the last row(containing total).

[image: example of the table]

[image: example of the table]

For example in the table below:

- For the first row, the grid span is 2 for the 1st cell and 3 for the 2nd cell (total cells 2).
- For the second row, the grid span is 2 for the 3rd cell and 1 for rest (total cells 4).
- For the last row, the grid span is 2 for 1st and 2nd cell. (total cells 3).

Do you have any suggestions on how to do that or what data structure should I use? I'm thinking of python dictionary, but can't implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dataframe. You use this data structure by importing the pandas library. Here is the documentation on it. It is a data structure that resembles the structure of a CSV

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html